# How to RESET YN560-TX PRO for Nikon after a failed firmware update?

Tags: yongnuo, firmware

Guys I just bought a YN560-TX PRO for Nikon and I did a firmware update and now is not turning on. Does any of you know how to do a factory reset, or something to help?

I really need this to work with my i-TTL YN685 (Nikon) flash.

Comment: You've done the press-and-hold the "clear" buttons with no improvement?

Comment: Hi Scott, I did, it works on my flash. The major problem is that it does not turn on. I can turn it on only for upgrade mode, after upgrade is done I switch it off and then.... it wont turn on. I am very disappointed.

Comment: where did you find the firmware?

Answer (score 1):

If the YN560-TX won't even power up or exit update mode, there's not much you can do besides return it to wherever you bought it for exchange or refund. If that's not an option, then you've got to decide if putting it on a slow boat back to China for factory service is worth the effort/cost (which likely will cost more than you paid for it).

If the only flash you have is a YN685, you might consider getting a YN622C-TX (if you're a Canon shooter) instead.

The YN685 is basically a YN622 system flash that can also be set to receive instructions from the YN560/RF605/RF603 system, but it is limited to the lower capabilities of the manual only YN560 system. A YN622 controller would allow you to fully exploit the wireless capabilities of your YN685 flash.

The YN560-TX PRO adds the ability to use TTL and other advanced functionality with YN622 system flashes in slave mode *if the YN622 system flash has the latest firmware installed.*

Existing YN685 flashes older than mid-2019 probably need a firmware update to be used in TTL mode with the YN560-TX Pro. The biggest issue is that some YN685 copies have early firmware versions that are not updateable. Even if the firmware is a version that is updatable, you need a YN622-TX to do it wirelessly since the YN685 has no usb port. If your YN685 (Canon) is not already running firmware version 2.0.2 or later it can not be updated. I have a YN685 that is firmware version 1.0.2 and there is no way to update the firmware, even when I'm using the latest firmware version for the YN622C-TX and latest version of YN Flash updater.

Or you could switch to Godox/Flashpoint (Adorama's private nameplate for Godox products). They seem to be more reliable than Yongnuo, and the Flashpoint version is backed by U.S. based Adorama so if you're in the U.S. you don't have to send stuff to China to get it serviced. The Godox/Flashpoint 2.4Ghz radio system also uses the same protocol for everything from their most basic manual speedlites all the way to their top end studio monolights.

Comment: Thank you Michael C! I will return the product tomorrow and I will get the YN622-TX  for nikon. Thank you very much for your reply. And I will take your suggestion about he Godox/Flashpoint, Any good advice into getting a HSS flash with a trigger for an off camera flash? I really want to work with this but my limit is $500CAD :D Thanks again.

Comment: @jimmy I've recently cut my losses with Yongnuo and switched to Flashpoint (Godox). (I can still use my YN685 attached to a Godox receiver which fools it into thinking it is a camera.) But I'm in the U.S., where Adorama/Flashpoint is based. I don't know how that would work if you are in Canada. Prices also vary highly from one country to the next for the same items. For example, the Canon BG-E20 that is about $200 in the U.S. is $600CAD north of the border. Most of the issues I talk about in my answer are Canon specific. But updating firmware for anything Yongnuo can be a convoluted mess.

Comment: Just read through [this thread at DP Review about folks trying to update their Nikon (and Canon) YN685s](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4058919?page=4).

Comment: sure I will, Thank you.

Comment: Comparable Godox/Flashpoint here in the U.S are about the same price or only slightly more expensive than their Yongnuo counterparts. The YN685 runs about $115. The Godox TT685 runs about $110 and has more features. The YN622C-TX runs about $40, the Godox XPro runs about $70.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get your hands on a previous version of the firmware and try using that.  I searched for version 1.04 (1.05 is the current one), but didn't find any results.  You could try contacting Yongnuo directly and see if they can point you to it.

Comment: It's kind of hard to update firmware if the device will not even turn on.

Comment: Hi @phil, The version I see on my model is V 1.00. That's probably the error. Can you please let me know where to find the V1.04 please. I will start the google hunt right now. :D I also email YN but they only replied once 2 days ago.

Comment: Hi @Michael, The triggers only turns on for upgrade, but not for triggering, :( If i find another version for the software it may work then. I will keep everyone posted.

Comment: Hi @Phil, I just check the website once again, I think I have the latest version for Nikon. YN560TX3N_FW_V1.00 the one you saw it is for canon YN560TX3C_FW_V1.05 :(

Comment: @jimmy Since the YN560-TX PRO was initially Canon only when announced in July, you probably should have included that you're using Nikon in your question. Updating YN685 (Canon version) flashes and YN685N (Nikon version) flashes are two entirely different animals. It's probably the same with the different versions of the YN560-TX controller.

Comment: You are right Michael, I should have add it the Nikon name, I try changing it afterwards but it wouldn't let me. I made sure the trigger was for nikon thought.

Comment: @jimmy Yeah, I just spent a couple of hours reading updated manuals and playing with my own Yongnuo pieces writing what turned out to be a useless answer for the Nikon version.